# What is the meaning of the "x" in script if [ "x$RUN_CONF" = "x" ]; then?

Tags: jboss

I have installed Jboss. IN run.sh file, what is the meaning of the "x" in this line. "if [ "x$RUN_CONF" = "x" ]".

Regards,
Sai

Answer (score 0):

Its a standard way in shell scripts to test if an environment variable has been defined.